# How to pass argument to an external script?

Tags: scripts

I want to pass some argument to an external script.
I try :

```
    \immediate\write18{./script \a\ \b\ \c > output.tex}
```

It works, but `\a` `\b` and `\c` are not given as three different arguments, but as one concatened string to the first argument.

How to pass three or more arguments ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"`\` " is a command for the typesetting engine of TeX, here you just need a space token that is provided by macro `\space`:

```
\immediate\write18{./script \a\space\b\space\c >output.tex}
```

Macro `\space` is defined in the LaTeX kernel as:

```
\def\space{ }
```